# Need to show subdomain as url than the directory path

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I have created a subdomain yesterday as www.subdomain.example.com. This has created a directory at the root by the name of subdomain. Now when i open www.subdomain.example.com, it gets redirected to www.example.com/subdomain. How to keep my url from showing the directory path i.e. in address bar it keep showing www.subdomain.example.com , while showing content from the directory subdomain.
I have  a shared hosting account at hostgator.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your .htaccess file, turn off the redirect and use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?subdomain\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdomain
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdomain/$1 [L]
```

This checks if the requested host is either `www.subdomain.example.com` or `subdomain.example.com` makes sure the request doesn't already start with a `/subdomain` and appends it otherwise. This redirects internally on the server so your browser doesn't actually get redirected (address bar will still say: subdomain.example.com).

Comment: Just solved the problem, code given by jon is correct. i was trying to upload .htaccess file to root while i should have uploaded to the subdomain directory. One little edit i did to jon code was on line 3rd . I gave full path to the directory . so the 3rd line of the code looked like RewriteContd %{REQUEST_URI)} http://www.example.com/subdomain

Comment: Weird, %{REQUEST_URI} doesn't include the hostname or the "http://", it's just the path (e.g. `/subdomain`). That condition will never match.

Comment: I had included full path with http://www. in my .htaccess file . I just have noticed that when i write full path in comment area in stackoverflow, it removes http://www. part but add a link. That's why it seems incorrect..I am new to stackoverflow. Sorry for the miss